# firebug console error

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, firefox3.6

I try to learn to use Firebug (debug).

I try to run "bennadel Firebug debug example".

URL SCRIPT http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1459-FireBug-s-Console-dir-vs-DOM-Tab.htm.

With:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 GTB6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729).
Firebug 1.5.2.

I run " FireBug Console Testing" ans see firebug console :I have a lot of errors and sometimes have stack overflow.

I try also to run windowsXP3  in Failure mode but I have also same errors.

Errors examples:

```
------------------------------------------------------
Error1.
p.onStateChange is not a function chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml Line
p.onStatusChange(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStatus, aMessage);
reference to undefined property window.oTidyBrowser
chrome://tidy/content/tidyBrowser.js  Line 220            
URL   Source de :///Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/chrome/browser.jar!/browser/tabrowser.xml-->  p.onStatusChange(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStatus, aMessage);

Error2.
p.onSecurityChange is not a function chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml Line  and same message (please see above).

X  warnings. example:
reference to undefined property context.sourceFileMap[url].
chrome://firebug/content/lib.js.
Line 2743.
Script:" FireBug Console Testing"

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title>FireBug Console Testing</title> 
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  // Define complex object.
  var objGirl = {
   Name: "Molly",
   Hair: "Brunette",
   Eyes: "Brown",
   BestQualities:
    [
    "Smile",
    "Laugh"
    ]
   }; 
  // Debug data in FireBug.
  console.dir( objGirl ); 
  // Update the complex object.
  objGirl.BestQualities = [
   "Legs",
   "Butt"
   ]; 
  // Debug updated data in FireBug.
  console.dir( objGirl ); 
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>
  FireBug Console Testing
 </h1>
</body>
</html>
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Please, how can you explain that.

I don't find the solution in web forums because I am a beginner and I do not know how intrepretive content of these messages errors.

Can I correct these errors and how?

Thank you.

Best regards,

alain.saez (Beginner French)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362898/firebug-console-error

Hello,
FireBug Console Testing
Errors (firefox 3.6 version).

No errors nor warnings in firebug 1.5.2 with firefox 3.5.8 version

Best regards,

alain saez

Answer (score 3):

It is very likely because of the `PDF Download` plugin.
Disable it, restart Firefox and check again.

Comment: It was the PDF Download plugin causing this for me as well. Thanks!